# Sum of the distincts Extended Description

Tags: java

I have an addition program:

```
import java.io.*;

public class sum
{
    int num; 
    int sum = 0;
    int result;

    public void findsum() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("enter the value for N : ");
        num = Integer.parseInt(Br.readLine());
        int nums[] = new int[num+1];

        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Enter " + i + " number: ");
            nums[i]= Integer.parseInt(Br.readLine());
            sum = sum + nums[i];
        }

        System.out.print("\n Sum  is : " + sum );
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        sum sm = new sum();
        sm.findsum();
    }
}
```

Output:

It takes N `Integer` values as input from the user and returns sum of those N numbers.

But I want if any of the number is equal to the other one it will automatically ignore them in addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just verify if the input number isn't in the array yet.

Change your for loop with this and it will work fine:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

    System.out.print("\n Enter the " + i + " number : ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(Br.readLine());
    int j=0;
    while(j<num && nums[j]!=x) {
    j++;
    }
    if(j>=num) {
    nums[i] = x;
    }

    sum = sum + nums[i];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question

> i want if any of the number is equal to the other one it will
>   automatically ignore them in addition

It will easy if you use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) here

```
Set<Integer> numbers=new HashSet<>();
for(int i = 1;i<=num;i++){ 
  System.out.print("\n Enter " + i + " number : ");
  numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(Br.readLine())); // add to set
```

}

Now duplicate values not consider. Then simply add elements in the `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues:

- Your for loop starts with 1 and the index of array that you used is nums[i] which means your array will start with 1. Array start with 0th index so used i-1 when you are referring index in for loop for your array or use loop starting from 0 till n-1.
- If you want to stick with your implementation with Array then in every for loop, before doing the sum you need to iterate over each earlier element to check if element already exist in an array something like:

  ```
  numberFound = false;  
  for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {  
      if (nums[j - 1] == nums[i - 1]) {  
          numberFound = true;  
          System.out.println("Duplicate number " + nums[i - 1]
              + " will be ignored");
          break;  
      }  
  }  
  if (!numberFound) {  
      sum = sum + nums[i - 1];  
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use Set to remove redundancy

```
Set<Integer> num = new HashSet<Integer>();
    num.add(123);
    num.add(123);
    num.add(1);
    num.add(1);

    Integer sum=0;
    for(Object a: num.toArray()){
        sum+=(Integer)a;
    }
    System.out.println(sum); //124
```

Answer (score 0):

When using **Java 8** you can let the [Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) do the work:

- [Stream#distinct()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--)

From the JavaDoc:

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to Object.equals(Object)) of this stream.

---

How to use:

```
final int[] nums = new int[] {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4};
final int sum = IntStream.of(nums)
    .distinct()
    .sum();

System.out.println(sum); // prints 10 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4);
```